# Can't update version of NPM - Stuck on 5.6.0 - Reinstalled with no success

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

As the title states, I am on Mac and I am stuck on npm version 5.6.0 and I can't seem to update it.

I have tried `sudo npm i -g npm` but I get the error

> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v16.10.0
> npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
> npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
> npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
> npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
> npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

I have tried uninstalling all of NPM including via brew, and reinstalled via the node website download, but it still seems to be stuck at 5.6.0?

Any clues as to what I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of managing Versions, the best way on unix based systems is nvm. You can install it with the install script from their repo https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm You should uninstall your installed version first. With the current lts Version of 18.16.0 you currently get npm version 9.5.1 packaged with.

Comment: I do have NVM installed and do usually use `nvm use xxx` for local development. But I made the mistake of doing an `npm i -g npm@xxx` yesterday, which has caused issues. Any clues on how to best uninstall things?

Comment: Did you run which npm to find out the path of your current npm path?